# Buscar HTML dentro de um iframe

Tags: c#, iframe

Estou com problemas em pegar os dados de uma [tabela no site da Bovespa](http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Cias-Listadas/Empresas-Listadas/ResumoEmpresaPrincipal.aspx?codigoCvm=9512&idioma=pt-BR), porque estão dentro de um `iframe` e eu não estou conseguindo acessá-la pelo WebBrowser,

Estou usando windowsForm.

Comment: Se você acessar o URL do iframe resolve o seu problema? Aqui: http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt-br/mercados/acoes/empresas/ExecutaAcaoConsultaInfoEmp.asp?CodCVM=9512&ViewDoc=1&AnoDoc=2013&VersaoDoc=8&NumSeqDoc=35079#a

Comment: Resolve sim, porem não teria uma forma mais pratica de fazer doque procurar o link do iframe e concatenar no do site?

Comment: Eu não vejo outra forma de obter o URL além dessa.

Comment: Veja que dá para usar o ID da CVM que está no primeiro URL (9512), aplicando no segundo URL. Isso te ajuda de alguma forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procure pelo URL do `iframe` na página, e abra com o webbrowser.

No caso do link que você passou, o URL é esse:

http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt-br/mercados/acoes/empresas/ExecutaAcaoConsultaInfoEmp.asp?CodCVM=9512&ViewDoc=1&AnoDoc=2013&VersaoDoc=8&NumSeqDoc=35079#a

Ou, dependendo do que você precisa, pode pegar o ID da CVM que está no primeiro URL (9512), e montar o segundo URL.